# Expressão regular inicio de palavra até proximo número

Tags: php, regex

Precisava de com uma expressão regular apanhar determinar grupo de uma string.

Imaginemos a seguinte string:

> (a >3) and ( b + c  = 4 and **M < 45**) and (d + e  = 6 and **M between 40 and 60**) and z>10

Precisava de capturar os grupos a negrito.
De notar que o primeiro é desde a expressão M até encontrar um número:
`M < 45`.

Contudo a mesma regra não se aplica para o seguinte caso, pois tem `between 40 and 60`, sendo que a mesma regra pararia no `M between 40`.

Alguém me pode dar uma ajuda em obter uma expressão regular para apanhar os casos a negrito?

Não tenho grande conhecimento das expressões regulares, por isso solicitava a ajuda da comunidade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>A princípio, regex pode não ser a ferramenta mais adequada, pois o que você precisa provavelmente é de um [*parser* de expressões lógicas](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20parser%20logical%20expression) (ou algo do tipo). Basta ver como a regex pode se tornar complicada, dependendo dos casos que quisermos tratar.</sup>

---

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/399754/112052) já mostra uma regex que não é lá muito simples, e ainda sim ela assume algumas premissas (e consequentemente, possui alguns possíveis problemas):

- ela assume que não existem variáveis cujos nomes têm mais de uma letra. Ou seja, não existe algo como `Mx > 10` (pois ela considera esses casos também, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/GBn79l/3/))
- a regex para números (`[\d\.]+`) é uma versão bem simplificada, pois considera que `....` e `1.2.3.4` são "números" válidos, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/1BeIey/1/). Então `M > ...` é considerada uma expressão válida ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/GBn79l/4/))
- o trecho que reconhece "between" reconhece qualquer sequência de letras, ou até mesmo nenhuma letra (apenas espaços), já que todo este trecho usa o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`, que significa "**zero** ou mais ocorrências" - sendo assim, poderia ter inclusive "zero letras" entre os números ([exemplos](https://regex101.com/r/GBn79l/6/))
- ainda há o fato de só reconhecer no mínimo dois dígitos (`M > 1` não é reconhecido, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/GBn79l/7/))

Claro que isso **não** quer dizer que ela está totalmente errada (exceto pelo último item, talvez). Se você garante que suas entradas sempre serão expressões válidas, não há problema nenhum em usar uma regex mais simples. É sempre importante balancear complexidade e conveniência: se a regex pega tudo que você quer, e também ignora tudo que você não quer, não precisa complicá-la à toa.

Dito isso, se quiser ser mais rígido, pode usar uma regex mais restrita (e o preço a se pagar é o aumento da complexidade):

```
$regex = '{
    (?(DEFINE)
       (?<number>    (?: -? (?: (?= [1-9]|0(?!\d) ) \d+ (?:\.\d+)? ) | \.\d+ ) )
       (?<variable>  (?: \bM\b ) )
       (?<clause>    (?: 
                         (?&variable) \s* [<>=] \s* (?&number) |
                         (?&variable) \s+ between \s+ (?&number) \s+ and \s+ (?&number)
                     ))
    )
    (?&clause)
}x';

$str = '(a > 3) and ( b + c = 4 and M < 45) and (d + e = 6 and M between 40 and 60) and z>10';
if (preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches)) {
    foreach ($matches[0] as $m) {
      echo $m. PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

O trecho `(?(DEFINE))` serve para [definir sub-rotinas](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#define). Cada trecho contendo `(?<nome>` define uma sub-rotina: uma "sub-regex" específica. Em seguida, podemos usar `(?&nome)`, que serve para usar a expressão definida pela sub-rotina "nome", e assim não termos que repetir a mesma regex várias vezes.

Repare, por exemplo, na regex para o número (que valida números negativos e com casas decimais, ignora valores como `000`, entre outros casos - [veja](https://regex101.com/r/bhUf7B/1/)), e veja quantas vezes ela se repete na sub-rotina "clause". Seria possível escrever esta regex sem sub-rotinas, mas a regex para números teria que ser repetida 3 vezes e ela ficaria gigante e ilegível.

Também usei a [*flag* `x`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), que ignora os espaços e quebras de linha e permite escrever a regex desta maneira, deixando-a um pouco menos confusa. Sem esta flag, eu teria que escrever tudo em uma única linha e sem espaços, e ficaria ilegível demais.

Basicamente, a regex define que a variável é `\bM\b`. O atalho `\b` ([*word boundary*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)) define uma "fronteira entre palavras" (uma posição com um caractere alfanumérico antes e um não-alfanumérico depois, ou vice-versa). Assim, eu garanto que só posso pegar a variável "M", mas não "Mx" ou "AM".

Na sub-rotina "clause" eu defino que ela pode ser duas coisas diferentes, usando [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`, que significa **ou**). ou seja, uma "clause" pode ser uma das duas opções:

- "M operador número": sendo que o operador é `[<>=]` (o sinal de maior, ou de menor, ou de igual). **Se quiser considerar também `>=` e `<=`**, pode trocar este trecho por `(?:[<>]=?|=)`.
- "M between número and número": aqui eu reaproveito a sub-rotina que definiu o número, e deixo bem claro que o texto só pode ser "**between** número **and** número". É [melhor ser mais específico](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want) para evitar casos como os já mencionados acima (aceitar qualquer texto entre os números, ou nenhum)

Sendo assim, a regex só vai pegar estes casos (assumindo que o M não fará parte de expressões aritméticas, como "M + 1 > 3", pois aí teríamos que incluir esses casos também).

O resultado é:

```
M < 45
M between 40 and 60
```

---

Claro que, se as expressões são sempre bem formadas e os números são apenas inteiros, você pode simplificar para:

```
$regex = '/\bM\b(\s*[<>=]\s*\d+|\s+between\s+\d+\s+and\s+\d+)/';
```

Ela basicamente segue a mesma lógica da anterior, mas tudo condensado em uma só regex. A única diferença significativa é a verificação de números, que usa somente `\d+` (um ou mais dígitos). Quebrando a regex em partes, temos:

- `\bM\b`: a variável "M" (usando o `\b` para evitar nomes como "Mx" ou "AM")
- alternância com duas opções:

  - `\s*[<>=]\s*\d+`: zero ou mais espaços (`\s*`), seguido do operador (e você pode trocar `[<>=]` por `(?:[<>]=?|=)` se quiser considerar também `>=` e `<=`), seguido de zero ou mais espaços e número, **ou**
  - `\s+between\s+\d+\s+and\s+\d+` :um ou mais espaços (`\s+`), "between", espaços, número, "and", espaços, número

---

Se quiser que o "between" e o "and" sejam *case insensitive* (tanto faz se estão em maiúsculas ou minúsculas), é possível usar:

```
$regex = '{
    (?(DEFINE)
       (?<number>    (?: -? (?: (?= [1-9]|0(?!\d) ) \d+ (?:\.\d+)? ) | \.\d+ ) )
       (?<variable>  (?: \bM\b ) )
       (?<clause>    (?: 
                         (?&variable) \s* [<>=] \s* (?&number) |
                         (?&variable) \s+ (?i) between \s+ (?&number) \s+ and (?-i) \s+ (?&number)
                     ))
    )
    (?&clause)
}x';
```

A indicação `(?i)` diz "a partir daqui, a regex é *case insensitive*", então eu só coloco isso antes do "between". E logo depois do "and" eu desligo esse modo, usando `(?-i)`. Ou seja, somente o trecho "between número and" é afetado (e como a regex de número só usa dígitos, tanto faz ele ser *case insensitive* ou não).

Eu não tornei a regex inteira *case insensitive* para que ela considere somente a variável "M" (ignorando variáveis chamadas "m").

Comment: Obrigado pelo contributo :)

Comment: Só mais uma questão.. Está a apanhgar apenas M<45, contudo tb precisaria de M <= 45 ou M >= 45
Obg

Comment: @Bruno Isso é mencionado na resposta: "Se quiser considerar também >= e <=, pode trocar este trecho por `(?:[<>]=?|=)`"

Comment: :) Muito obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Expressões regulares requerem regras bem definidas, como você mesmo não conseguiu definir uma regra para quando a expressão deveria continuar procurando por números, e só forneceu um exemplo, o que eu posso imaginar seria algo como isso: `/M\D*[\d\.]+\s*[a-zA-Z]*\s*[\d\.]+/`

---

Tentando entender:

`M` é o caractere inicial da sua sequência

`\D*` e´uma possível sequência de caracteres (0 ou mais), excluindo numéricos, ou seja espaços, `>`, `>=`, `between` são sequências válidas

`[\d\.]+` é uma sequência de caracteres (1 ou mais) numéricos, ou pontos. Estou considerando a possibilidade de um float.

`\s*[a-zA-Z]*\s*` é uma possível sequência de espaços, seguido de uma possível sequência de caracteres, seguida de outra possível sequência de espaços. Note que todos eles são opcionais.

---

Utilização:

```
$exp = '/M\D*[\d\.]+\s*[a-zA-Z]*\s*[\d\.]+/';
$str = '(a >3) and ( b + c = 4 and M < 45) and (d + e = 6 and M between 40 and 60) and z>10';

preg_match_all($exp, $str, $match);
$palavras_encontradas = $match[0];
```

Veja funcionando [aqui](https://ideone.com/KVbzmf).

Comment: Olá.. Reparei uma coisa.. Caso a Expressão seja M < 4 em vez de 45 não apanha..
só apanha 2 numeros para cima.
ex:
M < 4 não encontra
M < 45 encontra
M < 100 encontra..

alguma sugestão?

Comment: @Bruno Vc viu a minha resposta abaixo? Ela funciona pra esse caso: http://ideone.com/lTrEpf e http://ideone.com/n1lk05

Comment: Um detalhe (que muitas vezes eu também esqueço) é que dentro dos colchetes o ponto não precisa de *escape*, então pode ser apenas `[\d.]+`, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/UWQ7WT/1/)