# Qual a vantagem em usar as funções de expressão regular compatíveis com Perl ou as compatíveis com POSIX no PHP? Em que contexto usar uma e outra?

Tags: php, regex, posix

O PHP tem funções de expressões regulares compatíveis com Perl e com POSIX. Entretanto, não consigo vislumbrar se uma se sobressai a outra ou quais contextos de uso favorece uma ou outra.

Seria apenas uma questão de estilo ou preferência entre um padrão ou outro?

Comment: Segundo a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.regex.php), as funções posix estão deprecated no php 5.3 e foram removidas no php 7, então deixou de ser uma questão de preferência :-)

Comment: Tem razão. Estava devendo a documentação em português. Essa informação não consta na versão em português. Obrigado.

Comment: Não respondi ontem pq não tive tempo, mas está aí embaixo um detalhamento melhor das diferenças...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Segundo consta na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.regex.php), as funções compatíveis com regex POSIX (como [`ereg`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php) e [`ereg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php), entre outras) estão *deprecated* no PHP 5.3, e foram **removidas** no PHP 7. Então se estiver usando a versão 7, a única opção são as [regex PCRE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) (*Perl Compatible Regular Expressions*) e suas respectivas [funções `preg_*`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php) (como [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), etc).

---

Mas se estiver usando uma versão <= 5.3, acho que vale mencionar algumas diferenças importantes, inclusive algumas que [são mencionadas na documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php). Vamos ver alguns exemplos.

#### Classes de caracteres, atalhos e delimitadores

```
$str = 'abc123xyz';
if (preg_match('/\d+/', $str, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
if (ereg('[[:digit:]]+', $str, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Nas funções PCRE, a regex deve estar dentro de [delimitadores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83063/112052). No exemplo acima, usei as barras, ou seja, tudo que está entre os caracteres `/` é a regex, mas as barras em si não fazem parte da expressão. Já nas funções POSIX, os delimitadores não devem ser colocados. Ambas as chamadas acima retornam:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "123"
}
```

Outra diferença que podemos notar é a ausência do [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d` na regex POSIX. Em vez disso, devemos usar a classe especial `[[:digit:]]` para buscar qualquer dígito de 0 a 9 (esta classe também funciona em PCRE). Em ambos os casos também pode ser usada a [classe de caracteres](https://regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[0-9]`.

---

#### Outros atalhos

O mesmo vale para outros atalhos, como o `\w` (que pega letras, dígitos ou o caractere `_`), que em POSIX é **quase** equivalente a `[[:alnum:]]` (que só pega letras e dígitos, mas não o `_`):

```
$str = 'abc123_ xyz';
if (preg_match('/\w+/', $str, $matches)) {
    echo "PCRE\n";
    var_dump($matches);
}
if (ereg('[[:alnum:]]+', $str, $matches)) {
    echo "POSIX\n";
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

O `\w` também considera o caractere `_`, mas `[[:alnum:]]` não, por isso o resultado é:

```
PCRE
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "abc123_"
}
POSIX
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "abc123"
}
```

Se quisermos que a regex POSIX também considere o `_`, temos que mudar a expressão para `[[:alnum:]_]+`.

---

#### *Flags*

Outra diferença é que as regex PCRE possuem [*flags*/modificadores](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), que alteram alguns detalhes no funcionamento da expressão. Por exemplo, para fazer uma busca *case insensitive*, basta usar a *flag* `i`. Já as regex POSIX devem usar outra função específica para isso (no caso, [`eregi`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php)):

```
$str = 'ABCabc';
if (preg_match('/[a-z]+/', $str, $matches)) {
    echo "PCRE case sensitive\n";
    var_dump($matches);
}
if (preg_match('/[a-z]+/i', $str, $matches)) { // <- repare no "i" após a barra
    echo "PCRE case insensitive\n";
    var_dump($matches);
}
if (ereg('[a-z]+', $str, $matches)) {
    echo "POSIX case sensitive\n";
    var_dump($matches);
}
if (eregi('[a-z]+', $str, $matches)) {
    echo "POSIX case insensitive\n";
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Repare que na regex PCRE a *flag* `i` é colocada depois do delimitador final (após a última `/`), tornando a regex *case insensitive* (não diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas). Já para a regex POSIX, não existem *flags* e o único jeito é chamar outra função (`eregi`). O resultado é:

```
PCRE case sensitive
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "abc"
}
PCRE case insensitive
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "ABCabc"
}
POSIX case sensitive
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "abc"
}
POSIX case insensitive
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "ABCabc"
}
```

O PCRE possui outras *flags* para as quais não há equivalente em POSIX, como por exemplo a *flag* `m`, que faz com que os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` (respectivamente o início e fim da string) também correspondam ao início e fim de uma linha. Ex:

```
$str = "abc\n123\nxyz\n456";
if (preg_match('/\d$/m', $str, $matches)) {
    echo "PCRE\n";
    var_dump($matches);
}
if (ereg('[[:digit:]]$', $str, $matches)) {
    echo "POSIX\n";
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

As expressões buscam por um dígito seguido de `$`: na regex PCRE, por causa da *flag* `m`, indica que pode ser tanto o final da string quanto o final de uma linha. Por isso ela encontra o dígito `3` (`preg_match` sempre retorna a primeira ocorrência encontrada).

Já na regex POSIX, o `$` sempre corresponde ao final da string, então `ereg` encontra o dígito `6`. Para que ela encontre o `3`, eu teria que modificar um pouco a expressão, para considerar que depois do dígito pode ter um `\n` ou o final da string:

```
if (ereg("([[:digit:]])(\n|$)", $str, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[1]); // 3
}
```

Eu coloco o dígito entre parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), e como é o primeiro par de parênteses da regex, então ele estará no primeiro grupo - que pode ser recuperado com `$matches[1]`. Tive que fazer assim para pegar somente o dígito, pois se tiver um `\n`, ele também é retornado no *match* (como eu só quero o dígito, crio um grupo de captura contendo somente ele).

---

#### Algoritmo de *Match*

A regex PCRE começa a busca pelo início da string e retorna assim que encontra o primeiro *match*, enquanto a regex POSIX sempre retorna o maior *match* possível (o de maior comprimento). Usando o exemplo da documentação:

```
$str = "oneselfsufficient";
if (preg_match('/one(self)?(selfsufficient)?/', $str, $matches)) {
    echo "PCRE\n";
    var_dump($matches[0]); // oneself
}
if (ereg('one(self)?(selfsufficient)?', $str, $matches)) {
    echo "POSIX\n";
    var_dump($matches[0]); // oneselfsufficient
}
```

A regex busca pela string "one" seguida [opcionalmente](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) por "self", seguida opcionalmente por "selfsufficient". A regex PCRE retorna o primeiro *match* que encontrar: como ela inicia no começo da string, ela encontra o trecho "one", e depois verifica se o trecho "self" opcional está presente. Como está (pois a string contém "oneself") e o restante da expressão é opcional, o *match* "oneself" é retornado.

Já a regex POSIX testa todas as possibilidades para retornar o maior *match* possível (que no caso, é a string toda).

Dependendo da regex e das strings sendo buscadas, isso pode ter implicações de desempenho: como a PCRE retorna assim que encontra o primeiro *match*, ela *pode* ser mais rápida que a POSIX, que precisa testar todas as possibilidades para saber qual o maior dos *matches* encontrados.

---

## Outros recursos

Existem ainda outras diferenças que não são mencionadas na documentação:

#### Grupos de não-captura

PCRE possui suporte a [grupos de não-captura](http://rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#noncap). Quando eu **não** quero que os parênteses formem um grupo de captura, basta usar a sintaxe `(?: ... )`:

```
$str = "abc 123";
if (preg_match('/([a-z]+) (?:1)/', $str, $matches)) { // o "1" não é um grupo de captura
    echo "PCRE\n";
    var_dump($matches);
}
if (ereg('([a-z]+) (?:1)', $str, $matches)) { // ERRO! (expressão inválida)
    echo "POSIX\n";
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Na regex PCRE, somente as letras estão em um grupo de captura, já o número `1` não. Na regex POSIX, a sintaxe `(?:` gera uma regex inválida e dá erro:

```
PCRE
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "abc 1"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "abc"
}

Warning: ereg(): REG_BADRPT in /mnt/c/Users/hkotsubo/teste.php on line 8
```

Repare que no caso de `preg_match`, o array `$matches` possui 2 elementos: o primeiro é todo o *match* encontrado, e o segundo (na posição 1) é o primeiro - e único - grupo de captura.

---

#### Quantificadores preguiçosos

As regex PCRE possuem [quantificadores preguiçosos](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy).

Por padrão, quantificadores como `+` (uma ou mais ocorrências) e `*` (zero ou mais ocorrências) são "gananciosos" e tentam pegar a maior quantidade possível de caracteres. Mas é possível deixá-los "preguiçosos", o que faz com que eles peguem a menor quantidade que satisfaça a expressão.

Por exemplo:

```
$str = "a123";
if (preg_match('/a\d*/', $str, $matches)) {
    echo "PCRE\n";
    var_dump($matches); // a123
}
if (ereg('a[[:digit:]]*', $str, $matches)) {
    echo "POSIX\n";
    var_dump($matches); // a123
}
```

As expressões buscam pela letra `a` seguida de zero ou mais dígitos. Como o quantificador `*` é ganancioso, ele pega a maior quantidade possível (que no caso, é `a123`). Mas na regex PCRE é possível deixá-lo preguiçoso, adicionando um `?` na frente:

```
$str = "a123";
if (preg_match('/a\d*?/', $str, $matches)) {
    echo "PCRE\n";
    var_dump($matches); // a
}
if (ereg('a[[:digit:]]*?', $str, $matches)) { // ERRO!
    echo "POSIX\n";
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Com isso, a regex pega a menor quantidade de caracteres possível. Como `*` quer dizer **zero** ou mais ocorrências, então a menor quantidade possível de dígitos que ela pode pegar é zero. Com isso, `preg_match` encontra somente "a". Já a regex POSIX dá erro por não suportar este recurso.

Para mais detalhes sobre quantificadores preguiçosos, veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/415757/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401755/112052).

---

#### *Lookarounds*

Os [*lookarounds*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) são formas de se "olhar" para o que tem à frente ou atrás de determinada posição, sem que este faça parte do *match*. Ex:

```
$str = "a1 bc d3";
if (preg_match_all('/[a-z](?=\d)/', $str, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

A regex busca por uma letra de `a` a `z`, desde que depois dela exista um dígito. O *lookahead* `(?=\d)` verifica se existe um dígito à frente, mas este dígito não fará parte do *match*. O resultado terá apenas as letras `a` e `d`, pois as outras não possuem um dígito logo depois:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "d"
  }
}
```

Já se tentarmos fazer algo parecido com POSIX (algo como `[a-z](?=[[:digit:]])`) dará erro, pois ela não suporta *lookarounds*.

Repare também que usei [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) para trazer todas as ocorrências (pois `preg_match` traz apenas a primeira encontrada). Não existe um equivalente para POSIX (não há algo como `ereg_all`).

#### *Replace* com *callback*

Nas funções PCRE existe a possibilidade de se usar uma função de *callback* na substituição, usando [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/\b([A-Z]+)\b/', // procura por palavras todas em maiúsculas
    function ($match) {
        // deixa só a primeira letra maiúscula, o restante em minúsculo
        $word = $match[1];
        return $word[0]. strtolower(substr($word, 1));
    },
    'ABC def GHI X jkl'); // Abc def Ghi X jkl
```

Não há equivalente em POSIX.

#### E muito mais

Existem muitos outros recursos PCRE que não são suportados pelas regex POSIX, como [regex recursivas](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php), [comentários](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.comments.php), [grupos atômicos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.onlyonce.php), [Unicode *properties*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php), [*flags inline*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.internal-options.php), [condicionais](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.conditional.php), [*branch reset*](http://rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#branchreset), [verbos de controle](http://www.rexegg.com/pcre-doc/08.37/pcrepattern.html#SEC27) (tem um exemplo de uso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/447747/112052)), [sub-rotinas](http://rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#subroutines), etc...

Alguns desses recursos eu considero meio "esotéricos" e não costumo usar, pois geralmente servem para situações nas quais regex não é a melhor solução (por exemplo, sub-rotinas podem ser usadas para *parsing* - veja exemplos [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/384310/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/399745/112052) - mas usar um *parser* específico é muito melhor; regex recursiva pode ser usada para verificar parênteses/colchetes/chaves balanceados - veja exemplos [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/429402/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/354598/112052) - mas existem algoritmos mais simples para isso, sem precisar de uma regex complicada, etc).